# QueryDSL joins and subqueries with native SQL

Tags: java, spring-data, querydsl, native-sql

I use Spring Data and QueryDSL 3.2.4 and I want to implement the following SQL query with QueryDSLs native SQL API:

```
WITH ORDER_GROUP AS (   -- TODO have to merge this subquery into the main query
    SELECT 
        ordergroup
       ,count(ID) AS nofOrdersPerGroup 
       ,MIN(priority) as minPriority
       ,MIN(requesteddeliverytime) as minRequestedDeliveryTime
       ,MIN(creationtime) as minCreationTime
      FROM ORDERHEADER hh
     group by orderGroup      
),
ALL_ORDERS AS (   -- TODO have to merge this subquery into the main query
    SELECT h.ordercode
      , h.ordergroup
      , h.priority
      , h.requesteddeliverytime
      , h.creationtime
      , h.statecode
      , (SELECT COUNT(ID)
           FROM orderposition p
          WHERE p.orderheaderid = h.ID
        ) AS nof_positions_per_order
      , CASE
            WHEN h.ordergroup IS NOT NULL
            THEN g.nofOrdersPerGroup
            ELSE 1
        END AS nof_orders_per_group
      , CASE
            WHEN h.ordergroup IS NOT NULL
            THEN g.minPriority
            ELSE h.priority
        END AS most_important_prio
      , CASE
            WHEN h.ordergroup IS NOT NULL
            THEN g.minRequestedDeliveryTime
            ELSE h.requesteddeliverytime
        END AS earliest_del_time
      , CASE
            WHEN h.ordergroup IS NOT NULL
            THEN g.minCreationTime
            ELSE h.creationtime
        END AS earliest_cre_time
       FROM ORDERHEADER h left outer join ORDER_GROUP g on h.ordergroup = g.ordergroup
      WHERE 1=1  -- TODO have to add filter clauses here
)
 SELECT ordercode
  , ordergroup
  , priority
  , requesteddeliverytime
  , creationtime
  , statecode
  , nof_positions_per_order
  , nof_orders_per_group
  , most_important_prio
  , earliest_del_time
  , earliest_cre_time
   FROM ALL_ORDERS
ORDER BY most_important_prio
  , earliest_del_time
  , earliest_cre_time
  , priority
  , requesteddeliverytime
  , creationtime;
```

The join is not on a FK column but on some arbitrary attribute of the subquery ORDER_GROUP. This subquery aggregates some min / max valuse on on OrderHeader for later use in sorting.

The query types are:

```
package com.stoecklin.wms.entity;

import static com.mysema.query.types.PathMetadataFactory.*;

import com.mysema.query.types.path.*;

import com.mysema.query.types.PathMetadata;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.mysema.query.types.Path;
import com.mysema.query.types.path.PathInits;


/**
 * QOrderHeader is a Querydsl query type for OrderHeader
 */
@Generated("com.mysema.query.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QOrderHeader extends EntityPathBase<OrderHeader> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2006939562;
    public static final QOrderHeader orderHeader = new QOrderHeader("orderHeader");
    public final com.stoecklin.utility.database.QBaseEntity _super = new com.stoecklin.utility.database.QBaseEntity(this);
    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> actualDeliveryTime = createDateTime("actualDeliveryTime", java.util.Date.class);
    public final StringPath creationMode = createString("creationMode");
    //inherited
    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> creationTime = _super.creationTime;
    public final StringPath customerCode = createString("customerCode");
    public final StringPath customerOrderCode = createString("customerOrderCode");
    public final StringPath deliveryCode = createString("deliveryCode");
    public final StringPath deliveryNote = createString("deliveryNote");
    public final StringPath headerText = createString("headerText");
    public final NumberPath<Integer> hostId = createNumber("hostId", Integer.class);
    public final NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);
    //inherited
    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> lastUpdateTime = _super.lastUpdateTime;
    public final StringPath orderCode = createString("orderCode");
    public final StringPath orderGroup = createString("orderGroup");
    public final ListPath<OrderPosition, QOrderPosition> orderPositions = this.<OrderPosition, QOrderPosition>createList("orderPositions", OrderPosition.class, QOrderPosition.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);
    public final StringPath orderTypeCode = createString("orderTypeCode");
    public final StringPath priority = createString("priority");
    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> requestedDeliveryTime = createDateTime("requestedDeliveryTime", java.util.Date.class);
    public final StringPath setupType = createString("setupType");
    public final StringPath shippingMode = createString("shippingMode");
    public final StringPath stagingArea = createString("stagingArea");
    public final EnumPath<com.stoecklin.wms.enums.OrderHeaderState> stateCode = createEnum("stateCode", com.stoecklin.wms.enums.OrderHeaderState.class);
    public final StringPath stateReason = createString("stateReason");
    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> stateTime = createDateTime("stateTime", java.util.Date.class);
    //inherited
    public final NumberPath<Long> version = _super.version;

    public QOrderHeader(String variable) {
        super(OrderHeader.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QOrderHeader(Path<? extends OrderHeader> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QOrderHeader(PathMetadata<?> metadata) {
        super(OrderHeader.class, metadata);
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.stoecklin.wms.entity;

import static com.mysema.query.types.PathMetadataFactory.*;

import com.mysema.query.types.path.*;

import com.mysema.query.types.PathMetadata;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.mysema.query.types.Path;
import com.mysema.query.types.path.PathInits;


/**
 * QOrderPosition is a Querydsl query type for OrderPosition
 */
@Generated("com.mysema.query.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QOrderPosition extends EntityPathBase<OrderPosition> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2091670278;
    private static final PathInits INITS = PathInits.DIRECT2;
    public static final QOrderPosition orderPosition = new QOrderPosition("orderPosition");
    public final com.stoecklin.utility.database.QBaseEntity _super = new com.stoecklin.utility.database.QBaseEntity(this);
    public final StringPath articleCode = createString("articleCode");
    //inherited
    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> creationTime = _super.creationTime;
    public final NumberPath<Integer> customerOrderPos = createNumber("customerOrderPos", Integer.class);
    public final NumberPath<Float> deliveredQuantity = createNumber("deliveredQuantity", Float.class);
    public final StringPath fromWarehouseCode = createString("fromWarehouseCode");
    public final StringPath hostData = createString("hostData");
    public final StringPath hostRef = createString("hostRef");
    public final NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);
    //inherited
    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> lastUpdateTime = _super.lastUpdateTime;
    public final StringPath lotCode = createString("lotCode");
    public final NumberPath<Float> missingQuantity = createNumber("missingQuantity", Float.class);
    public final QOrderHeader orderHeader;
    public final NumberPath<Integer> orderPos = createNumber("orderPos", Integer.class);
    public final StringPath ownerCode = createString("ownerCode");
    public final StringPath posText = createString("posText");
    public final NumberPath<Float> requestedQuantity = createNumber("requestedQuantity", Float.class);
    public final EnumPath<com.stoecklin.wms.enums.OrderPositionState> stateCode = createEnum("stateCode", com.stoecklin.wms.enums.OrderPositionState.class);
    public final StringPath stateReason = createString("stateReason");
    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> stateTime = createDateTime("stateTime", java.util.Date.class);
    public final StringPath toBePicked = createString("toBePicked");
    public final StringPath toLocation = createString("toLocation");
    //inherited
    public final NumberPath<Long> version = _super.version;

    public QOrderPosition(String variable) {
        this(OrderPosition.class, forVariable(variable), INITS);
    }

    public QOrderPosition(Path<? extends OrderPosition> path) {
        this(path.getType(), path.getMetadata(), path.getMetadata().isRoot() ? INITS : PathInits.DEFAULT);
    }

    public QOrderPosition(PathMetadata<?> metadata) {
        this(metadata, metadata.isRoot() ? INITS : PathInits.DEFAULT);
    }

    public QOrderPosition(PathMetadata<?> metadata, PathInits inits) {
        this(OrderPosition.class, metadata, inits);
    }

    public QOrderPosition(Class<? extends OrderPosition> type, PathMetadata<?> metadata, PathInits inits) {
        super(type, metadata, inits);
        this.orderHeader = inits.isInitialized("orderHeader") ? new QOrderHeader(forProperty("orderHeader")) : null;
    }

}
```

Now the questions:

1. How do I have to do the join at the bottom of the ALL_ORDERS subquery? I already tried the following:

   ```
   QOrderHeader orderHeader = QOrderHeader.orderHeader;
   QOrderHeader orderHeaderGroup = new QOrderHeader("orderHeaderGroup");
   QOrderPosition orderPosition = QOrderPosition.orderPosition;

   List<Tuple> tuples = query.from(orderHeader)
           .leftJoin(orderHeader, orderHeaderGroup).on(orderHeader.orderGroup.eq(orderHeaderGroup.orderGroup))
           .list(
                   orderHeader.orderGroup,
                   orderHeader.id
                 );
   ```

but this even won't compile because there is no matching method leftJoin available.
The join is not on a FK column but on some arbitrary attribute. The subquery ORDER_GROUP

1. How is the correlated subquery implemented which computes the nof_orders_per_group (7th item in SELECT list)? (I have no clue how tho do this :-))

The SQL shown on the top is somewhat optimized for efficiency. For that reason I decided to use native SQL because we have subqueries all around.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Querydsl with SQL then you need to create the metamodel in a different way, which is described here http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.4/reference/html/ch02s03.html

And to your more specific questions:

1)  FROM ORDERHEADER h left outer join ORDER_GROUP g on h.ordergroup = g.ordergroup

```
from(h).leftJoin(g).on(h.ordergroup.eq(g.ordergroup))
```

2) CASE
            WHEN h.ordergroup IS NOT NULL
            THEN g.nofOrdersPerGroup
            ELSE 1
        END AS nof_orders_per_group

```
new CaseBuilder()
    .when(h.ordergroup.isNotNull()).then(g.nofOrderPerGroup)
    .otherwise(1)
```

Concerning query construction, joins work different from JPA

Querydsl JPA

```
query.join(entity.property, reference)
```

Querydsl SQL

```
query.join(table).on(condition)
```

or alternatively

```
query.join(table.fk, otherTable)
```

Comment: Thanks Timo for the quick help. I changed the metamodel generation but first didn't get the query running but after carefully implementing your example the join works now. How / where do I implement then the subquery `(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM orderposition p WHERE p.orderheaderid = h.ID)`? Is this done in the list() part (like SQL)?

Comment: sq().from(p).where(p.orderheaderid.eq(h.id)).unique(id.count(), where sq() would return a new `SQLSubQuery` instance.